# Set default floor shown - Android Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google maps V2 in Android. As you know, nowadays Google lets us see floor plans inside some buildings. I'm displaying my position inside my University in a map, but last one only let me see first floor by default (for example if i'm in the second i have to change it manually). I searched in forums and i checked GMaps V2 documentation, but i didnt find any solution..

Do you know any map option, parameter or something else to set the default floor level?

Regards.